# Edit: Merge list into another list that is null, it is possible?

Tags: c#, linq, list

It is possible to add ListB PurchaseOrderHeader and Supplier into List A PurchaseOrderHeader and Supplier? I had try join, concat, but it see like not working well

POLine.

**List A**
[image]

**List B**
[image]

**Edit**

Sorry for forgot to add code

```
      POLine.Select(c => c.PurchaseOrderHeader).Concat(DataFromParent.Select(c=>c.PurchaseOrderHeader));
```

**Update**

It is possible to make it?

List A PurchaseOrderHeader = null,
 PurchaseOrderLine =some value ,
 Supplier  = null

List B only have 
 PurchaseorderLine = null,

can anyhow merge it to make it

List A PurchaseOrderheader = List B PurchaseOrderHeader, 
List A PurchaseOrderLine  remain,
 and List A Supplier = List B Supplier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very hard to understand what exactly you're asking but I think you might just be looking for the following:

```
// I think this is what you mean with list A and List B
var listA = POLine[0];
var listB = DataFromParent[0];

listA.PurchaseOrderHeader = listB.PurchaseOrderHeader;
listA.Supplier = listB.Supplier;
```

Comment: It is unbelievable for you to understand what I actually try to ask, but you actually giving the answer that I want, thanks for the help, and sorry for my bad explanation

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
List<string> a = new List<string>();
List<string> b = new List<string>();

a.AddRange(b);[this question is already asked][1]
```

Comment: Sorry, I want to merge, where the null value in List A replace by the value from List B

Comment: If you know that the question already has an answer, why repost it verbatim? The correct thing to do is mark the question as a duplicate by flagging/voting to close or leaving a comment in the OP if you lack those privileges.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, there is no "List A PurchaseOrderHeader": there is a variable "PurchaseOrderHeader", but that variable has no value.

You should first check if it has a value. If it does, you can add the other list to it. If it does not, you might want to assign List B to the variable `PurchaseOrderHeader`

```
if (listA == null) listA = listB;
else listA.AddRange(listB);
```

Judging from your code, it's not clear whether `PurchaseOrderHeader` is actually a List, so I'm not sure whether `.AddRange` is actually an option for you.

Comment: anywhere to merge replace the null value from list B? is it possible?

Comment: Currently now List A PurchaseOrderHeader = null,PurchaseOrderLine =some value Supplier  = null and List B only have PurchaseorderLine = null, can anywhere to merge it to make it List A PurchaseOrderheader = List B PurchaseOrderHeader, List A PurchaseOrder Line  remain, and List A Supplier = List B Supplier?

Answer (score 1):

This should solve your problem

```
List<t> list1=new list1<t>();
List<t> list2=new List<t>();        
list2.AddRange(list1);
```